# CardView, находящиеся внутри GridLayout, выезжают за экран

Tags: android

Проблема заключается в следующем:

[[image: введите сюда описание изображения][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npub4.png)

На превьюшке, однако, разметка выглядит иначе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:columnCount="2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CardView" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CardView"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</GridLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Предположу что вам можно попробовать поэксперементировать с параметром: android:layout_gravity="fill". И еще, исправьте: android:layout_margin="10dp" так чтобы не было по середине такого пространства, не очень хорошо смотрится...

Comment: @Valeriy, спасибо за Ваш ответ. Но вопрос, как оказалось, решается иначе. Сейчас опубликую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, как решается вопрос:

1) Тег `<GridLayout>`заменяется на `<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>`.

2) Подключается библиотека `'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'`.

3) Разметка меняется на соответствующую:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    app:columnCount="2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="fill">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CardView" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="fill">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CardView"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]